# Animate Number and Text when reach a certain point in the HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, numbers, nan

I want to count numbers with text when scrolling down my HTML file and reach a certain section. The code looks like this:

```
<h3 class="count">25 Years</h3>
<p>On the Road...</p>

<h3 class="count">143 Million</h3>
<p>Transactions worldwide 2015</p>
```

```js
$('.count').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that I only get a correct result when I put in only a number. If I put in a string like `25 Years`, it outputs `NaN`.

Any suggestions for my code?

```
var targetOffset = $(".company-numbers").offset().top;

        var $w = $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ( $w.scrollTop() > targetOffset ) {
                (function () {
                    $('.count').each(function () {
                        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
                            Counter: $(this).text()
                        }, {
                            duration: 4000,
                            easing: 'swing',
                            step: function (now) {
                                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                })();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because your jQuery code expects the value to be able to be parsed to an integer. Try putting the values to be counted in their own elements, for example `<span>`, and then call the jQuery logic on those values.

```
<h3><span class="count">25</span> Years</h3>
<p>On the Road...</p>

<h3><span class="count">143</span> Million</h3>
<p>Transactions worldwide 2015</p>
```

Comment: this works but if i put this in a conditional statement the code counts up, but then start counting down after.... i try return false but it didnt work out....please check my first post for the code...

Answer (score 0):

You have  to assign number values to elements if you want to operate like a create an array with key values inside your function or a JSON.

Comment: Welcome to SO but please provide your answer with an example or provide a reference link for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code , do you really want it like this?
and let me know!!!

```
<h3 class="count">25 Years</h3>
<p>On the Road...</p>

<h3 class="count">143 Million</h3>
<p>Transactions worldwide 2015</p>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
   $('.count').each(function () {
                $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
                    Counter: $(this).text().match(/\d/g).length
                }, {
                    duration: 4000,
                    easing: 'swing',
                    step: function (now) {
                        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                    }
                });
            });
            </script>
```

or if you want to count total number of characters then please change "counter" property.

```
Counter: $(this).html().length
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav, thank you for you suggestion. Unfortunately .match(/\d/g).length and .html().length are not putting out the correct numbers/strings.

Comment: Hi @151RUM do you actually want to count number of characters from string of "count" class?

Comment: No , i want to animate the content of the count class, for example 40.000 Units of something then it should count from zero to 40000 in 4 seconds when reach the content in HTML file... you get it mate ? :)